# Python and shell command

Tags: python, shell

I have next python code:

```
exec_cmd = "time"
print exec_cmd  
gzip_cmd = subprocess.Popen(exec_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = gzip_cmd.communicate()[0]
print out
```

When I try to execute this code I got next:

```
time
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
```

But when I try to run this command in terminal I got:

```
time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want to run a program/script named "time" in the same folder as your python script? Then you need to use "./time", because the current working directory in not in the $PATH in Un*x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" is that `time` is a Bash built-in, so it's different between Bash and `/bin/sh` (assuming that's not an alias for Bash--it isn't in Debian/Ubuntu).